# Running shell command 'unzip' with os.system call in python hangs halfway through extraction

Tags: python, unzip, os.system

The following block executes and extracts files until it gets to one particular file and then it just hangs.

```
#Unzip
unzip_cmd = f"unzip temp/temp.zip -d temp/unzip_output/"
os.system(unzip_cmd)
```

When executing in terminal, the command runs the entire way through. I've tried using subprocess.run() with the same result.

Comment: Could you please share you OS and python version?

Comment: Two questions. 1) Are you unzipping from and to *exactly* the same directories and files in your subprocess as in your terminal? 2) Does it always stop on exactly the same specific file?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same, I'm copying the command in and am in the same directory. Not always the same file. Python version is 3.10.8; OS is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: and yes, it's the same file each time.

Comment: Huh? Your last 2 comments appear to contradict each other?

Comment: Whoa, my fault - I meant it doesn't stop on the same file each time, I'm trying to extract the same file each time.